# How to upload image with text field name and preview image with name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Upload image with select field name and  Image Preview with selected name and  upload to database ? pls help me .... please see this image for example..
 [example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp3R3.jpg) i want this type of code to upload images with name.

Comment: yes, I think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.Anyway i can show you how to preview image on uploading..

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (e) {
     $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

}

```
$("#imgInp").change(function(){

   readURL(this);

 });
```

and the associated HTML:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
  </form>
```

Comment: sir please see example image.

Comment: @RahulSaini SO members can help you but we're not here to write your code. There are plenty of online resources on how to upload files.